# put page-$slug.php template inside a subdirectory not working

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have a page-again.php template, It is working when I put this template under my theme directory (/minim/page-again.php). I want to create an subdirectory page-templates(/minim/page-templates/page-again.php) and it's not working. I read a lot of thread and followed what they said. like this one  http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The template folder doesn't support specialized page templates. but it works for the custom page template.